# objC three20 example ttnavigator menu controller page instance declaration

Tags: objective-c, three20, instance-variables, ttnavigator

I tried to understand the three20 ttnavigator example code, and in the MenuController.h file, it is as follows:

```
typedef enum {
  MenuPageNone,
  MenuPageBreakfast,
  MenuPageLunch,
  MenuPageDinner,
  MenuPageDessert,
  MenuPageAbout,
} MenuPage;

@interface MenuController : TTTableViewController {
  MenuPage _page;
}

@property(nonatomic) MenuPage page;
```

@end

I don't understand why there is a MenuPage _page declared as an instance variable, while there is another variable MenuPage page declared in the @property section.  In the MenuController.m file, MenuPage page is synthesized, not _page.

Is this legal?

I know it works, because it compiles, but I don't understand why we don't need to set an `@property (nonatomic, retain) MenuPage _page`
or declare `MenuPage page` in the interface.

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, but why would we want to separate the ivar from the property if we're going to set them equivalent at synthesis?

Answer (score 0):

This line in MenuController.m

```
@synthesize page = _page;
```

connects the property to the ivar. (It tells the compiler to use the `_page` ivar to store the value of the `page` property.)